# Поиск улицы заданного города

Tags: поиск, ajax, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, геолокация

Как можно сделать ajax-поиск улицы по первым введенным буквам определенного города?
Где можно достать базу всех улиц?
Возможно ли сделать как-то, используя google maps или yandex?

[Пример](http://moscow.rutaxi.ru/index.html) поле A-B.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее уж
http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Там открытое API, можно реализовать свой функционал.